# Create reusable VueJS Template to use as component named template slot

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, primevue

I'm using PrimeFaces (PrimeVue) for my front end component UI.

For my main app layout I'm using several copies of the `<Menubar>` Component ([docs link](https://primevue.org/menubar/)). This component has a template slot named #item which you can set to override how the items in the menu are rendered.

Since I have 3 or 4 different menus on the page and all have exact same #item slot template code, I would prefer to write the `<template #item="{}">` code a single time, and then use it for the #item slot for each instance of `<Menubar>` on my page.

I tried following the instructions at https://vueuse.org/core/createReusableTemplate/ to create a template that I could use for this but something doesn't line up and the `<Menubar>` component acts as if I did not pass a `<template #item>` at all (as indicated by the fact it uses the built in display instead of the template provided).

I also tried making my own "component" that mimics the slot props and tried using that in place of the `<template #item>` tag and also as a child of it, and nothing I have tried seems to work.

It's not really the end of the world, but I am now just curious if this is something that is even possible and if so, I'm more curious as to how to accomplish it. Any time I can minimize duplicate code I will strive for it, no matter how big or small.

Here is an example of what I tried with `createReusableTemplate`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <DefineTemplate name="#item" v-slot="{$slots, label, item, props, root, hasSubmenu}">
            <span v-if="condition">something</span>
            <span v-else="condition2">something else</span>
        </DefineTemplate>
        <Menubar :model="menuItems">
            <ReuseTemplate />
        </Menubar>
    </div>
</template>
```

I also tried specifying the main element like this:

`<DefineTemplate #item="{ label, item, props, root, hasSubmenu }">`

and just (without name="#item" or $slots):

`<DefineTemplate v-slot="{ label, item, props, root, hasSubmenu }">`

I also tried for the ReuseTemplate Element, things like:

`<ReuseTemplate #item="{ label, item, props, root, hasSubmenu }" />`

Obviously I'm not super clear on how the named slot props are set and corelate with these reusable template elements...

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?